# One loop corrections to Compton scattering

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, feynman-diagrams, gluons

At next to leading order, a photon may couple to gluon via means of a quark loop insertion. Consider the process $$ \gamma(k_1) + g(p_1) \rightarrow \gamma(k_2) + g(p_2)$$ The six non zero diagrams are shown in the image (the pencilled in momenta is due to me, time flows from left to right so I think we always have a $k_1$ and  a $p_1$ on the left hand side and $k_2$ and $p_2$ on the right)

I understand that diagrams 3), 4), 5) and 6) are different but I don't see how diagrams 1) and 2) make sense. I redrew diagrams 5) and 6) to have the standard box structure of 3) and 4) (in 5) and 6) the two gluons are on vertices diagonally across from each other when drawn in this way) and with a different direction of route momentum this would ultimately give different integral representations for these two processes.

When I redraw 1) and 2) in a similar manner, I get $p_2$ as an initial state particle (i.e appearing on the left of the diagram) and $p_1$ as a final state one (i.e appearing on the right) so I don't see how this diagram contributes.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Basically what I want to understand is how I can redraw diagrams 1) and 2) so that they take the form of one of the two topologically distinct diagrams as follows [image]

I can do this for diagrams (3)-(6) but not for (1)-(2) because otherwise I would have $p_2$ on the left hand side of the diagram and, as Solenodon Paradoxus also points out in the comment below, this amounts to interchanging my incoming and outgoing states. So, can I redraw (1) and (2) so that I get $p_1$, $k_1$ ($p_2, k_2$)  on the left (right) hand side of the diagram?

Comment: You cannot redraw a diagram in such a way that changes incoming and outgoing particles. Why would you even want to do that? Whats wrong with the graphs on the picture?

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus: Thanks for your comment - can you check my edit in the updated version of my post? I think this might better explain my question. Thanks!

Comment: Would you accept "you can't" as an answer? Actually, I was trying to ask you why do you even expect this to be possible. What's wrong with the way those diagrams look? Feynman's rules *don't* require the graph to be planar, that is without intersecting propagators. However these intersections are unphysical and have absolutely no effect on the resulting amplitude, of course.

Comment: Sure, I would accept 'you can't' as an answer. I just remember reading in a paper somewhere that the two planar diagrams i posted in my edit were the two topologically distinct contributions so thought all diagrams (1)-(6) must reduce to something resembling them. But, indeed, diagrams (1)-(6) make sense to me too, we have two initial states and two final ones and everything that happens in between are all possible routings of the internal momentum :)